# Qt5 QuickView cannot create window: no screens are available

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qquickview

I receive this error (title, below) whenever I try to run the following code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("app.qml"));
    QObject *object = (QObject*)view.rootObject();

    view.show();

    delete object;
    return app.exec();
}
```

> Cannot create window: no screens available
>
> The program has unexpectedly finished.

All I can find online for that error are bug reports arising from specific conditions significantly more involved than the above.

`app.qml` is a file that runs fine alone, i.e. without the above C++ and in a separate project configured as a 'Qt Quick UI'. Giving it's `qrc://` path, or deliberately specifying a file which does not exist has no effect.

Note the `QObject*` cast - this was not present in [the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html), but without it:

> /main.cpp:11: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'QObject *' with an rvalue of type 'QQuickItem *'

How should this be done?

Answer (score 2):

The `QCoreApplication` can be used with **console application**, not with GUI ones, i.e. you have to use a `QGuiApplication` object. It seems to me that you created a console application instead of a graphical one.

You can create a proper application via the `Qt Quick Application`, add your "app.qml" as a resource to that project and call such a file instead of the default "main.qml", provided by the project template.

---

If you want to quick fix your current project, just check that the .pro file is set to import GUI libraries:

```
QT += gui qml quick
```

Set your qml file as a resource:

1. Create a new resource file via `file -> new File or Project... -> Qt -> Qt Resource File`
2. Right click the newly created `.qrc` file and click `add existing file` to add your "app.qml" file

Finally, rewrite your main like this:

```
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QGuiApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);    // GUI APPLICATION!!!
    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///app.qml")));
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

However, going for the `Qt Quick Application` project would be the wiser choice.

Comment: Note: For having the native style of the host operating system, use `QApplication` instead of `QGuiApplication`.

Comment: Good point. However, for QML applications not using `QWidget`-derived classes, `QGuiApplication` should be preferred since it has no dependencies on `QtWidgets` library.

Comment: Ok, right - didn't know that yet :) So with `QtWidgets`-dependencies you mean QtQuick-`Button`s, `TextField`s etc.?

Comment: `QPushButton`, `QTextEdit` and so on. Basically everything you add with `QT += widgets`. If you don't need them (and you usually don't, in a QML application) there's no need for another dependency.

Comment: So, when I'm for example on Windows and only make use of QML / QtQuick components, then there is no need for the QWidgets dependency? But how can I achieve a native style without this then (because the native look and feel is one of the major advantages of Qt) --> so nevertheless I will need this dependecy? (I think I've read this in the Qt docs somewhere)

Comment: As far as I know Digia is implementing styles for Quick controls and adding a platform on each release (`Android` style comes with 5.4). If the platform is supported you don't need the dependency. Or at least I intended it that way. I don't know if I'm wrong or if it is something only meant for mobile platforms. Sorry. 

However, no one said our statements are in contrast! :D AFA you don't need features based on `QtWidget` you should go with `QGuiApplication` to reduce dependencies. If styling is based only on `QtWidgets` just use `QGuiApplication`.

Comment: Ok, allright. This was what I remembered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770426/in-qt-qml-controls-applicationwindow-lacks-the-native-looking-theme-when-run  Not sure if this still applies.

Comment: I see, and by the way I've trusted your words before! From the `.pro` file of the gallery example we have: `!android: !ios: !blackberry: qtHaveModule(widgets): QT += widgets`. Now the question is: that platforms are removed because no default style is provided or the styles are (will be) added to the `QtQuickControls`? Probably the first one. You know what? I'm going to try that example on Android with 5.4.0 RC ASAP. :)

Comment: This certainly needs some more documentation :[] Well and yes, I think waiting for 5.4 (or using the RC) might clarify this :)

Comment: The RC example has code `!no_desktop: QT += widgets`. Removing the line results in a default L&F on my Windows machine whereas my 4.4 device has a nice `Android` feel (differently from 5.3). Pretty must settle down: following the example, use the row above in `.pro` file and then use `QT_WIDGETS_LIB` to import/use `QGuiApplication` or `QApplication` accordingly. Probably the desktop themes will remain bound to the widget library, don't know about that. However, having such a dependency on a desktop environment is not that awful.

Comment: Ahh great research! So in summary: desktops need this dependency (at least with Qt 5.4) and they need the `QApplication` while mobiles can drop this dependency and easily use `QGuiApplication`.

Comment: `Android` is the first supported, `iOS` will be supported in one of the next releases as I remember. That's actually confirmed by the 5.4RC on my MAC: correct style on desktop with `widgets`, default theme on the iPad. That's it.