# How to access native styles for qml apps?

Tags: qt, qml, mobile-application

I'm currently working on an application with qml and I really like it. But there is something I couldn't figure out. I'm searching something like the QML SystemPalette but for styles of specific elements. I hope there is something that would look like this:

```
Button {
    SystemStyles { id: styles }

    text: "A button"
    style: styles.button

}
```

But if there is no way of doing this, how can I build natively looking desktop apps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Qt Qml Controls, ApplicationWindow lacks the native-looking theme when run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770426/in-qt-qml-controls-applicationwindow-lacks-the-native-looking-theme-when-run)

Comment: In `Android` the L&F is set by default (for >= 5.4), other Mobile platform styles will be added in future releases. For what concern desktop you need to use `QApplication` instead of `QGuiApplication` and add `QT += widgets` to the project file: the native style is set automatically on `QuickControls`.